# Global helper function capable of accessing Zend objects

Tags: php, zend-framework

Currently I'm using a view-helper to help my debugging process. Basically I call this function and it checks if 1: I'm logged in as a developer by checking a Zend_Session_Namespace variable and 2: if the application is run in debug_mode using Zend_Registry. If both of them are true I show a number of different debug variables and any parameters I give the helper as input.

Originally this function was only intended to check that I got the right info in the objects assigned to the view, but I quickly discovered that it was useful in other places as well. At the moment the function works in controllers using $this->view, and I guess I could technically use something along new Zend_View(); or Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer'); to get a view-object in my models, but that is just plain ugly even if it's only for debugging.

So my question is: How can I rebuild this helper into a global function (usable in models, views and Controllers) and still be able to use the Zend_Session_Namespace and Zend_Registry objects, while (as far as possible) maintaining the MVC structure.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown

Comment: "Action Helpers allow developers to inject runtime and/or on-demand functionality into any Action Controllers that extend Zend_Controller_Action" 

My controllers extend Zend_Controller_Action but my views and models do not, so this would force me to write at least two copies of the same function.

Comment: No, you can pass the helper from the controller to the view if needed. or does that not fit your use pattern?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. My primary problem is that I want to use the same function(s) within the models as well as the view/controller. While I could theoretically pass helpers to the models as well, it would be cumbersome and would probably require quite some rewriting. I'm looking for something more like Zend_Debug::dump, but without the limitations of a static function since I don't want to output debug info in the production environment by mistake, and the content of the information might depend on the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you made a static class or a singleton class, you could have all of the desired functionality without breaking your MVC structure at all.

Consider the following simple class with one static function:

```
<?php

class My_DebugHelper
{
    public static function dump()
    {
        $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('the_namespace');  // the namespace you refer to with the developer flag
        $debug_mode = Zend_Registry::get('debug_mode');

        if (!isset($ns->isDeveloper) || !$ns->isDeveloper || !$debug_mode) {
            return;
        }

        foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($arg);
        }
    }

    protected function __construct() {} 
    protected function __clone() {}
}
```

This code gives you:

- The ability to call from anywhere in your application (model, controller, helper, view etc)
- All of the protections to prevent it from being executed when called out of context
- A simple base that you can expand upon

Depending on your needs, at least one thing you could do is make it static so it could store some of the information rather than access it each call, or add additional methods or specialized parameters so you could pass a `Zend_View` object to it if necessary and have data injected into the view.

You could call it from anywhere in your application and pass one or more values to dump:

```
My_DebugHelper::dump($someVar, $this->view, $model->getCustId());
```

I'm not sure how/what your view helper displays data currently, but hopefully that will help you merge your view helper into the generic class that you can call anywhere.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for but I din't manage to include the functions a part of the framework structure. Now it works brilliantly.